# Как получить готовый entity при выборке нескольких полей hibernate 5.2 java

Tags: java, hibernate, java-ee

Подскажите пожалуйста, как сделать что бы после выполнения запроса:

```
session.createQuery("select ue.email, ue.password 
                     from UserEntity ue 
                     where ue.email = :email 
                       and ue.password = :password")
```

hibernate(ver 5.2) вернул готовый UserEntity.

Comment: Не делать выборку конкретных полей. Просто `from UserEntity ue where ue.email = :email and ue.password = :password`

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev а если мне нужно только 2 поля из таблицы и что бы hibernate мне сразу вернул готовый объект?

Comment: Вы можете в UserEntity завести конструктор, принимающий два этих аргумента и тогда можно будет делать так `select new UserEntity(ue.email, ue.password) from UserEntity ue where ue.email = :email and ue.password = :password`. Но учитывайте, что в результате запроса вы получите не сущность, а просто отсоединённый объект. Если попытаетесь его сохранить, будет создана новая сущность.

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev и еще вопрос что лучше использовать HQL или Criteria?

Comment: А это уж вам решать. JPQL проще и лаконичнее, но критерия обеспечивает проверку типов на этапе компиляции.

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev если можно то опишите подробнее в чем + и - 
и когда будет рационально использовать тот или иной язык запросов. (или если есть хорошая статья на рус языке то и ссылку можно)
Напишите в ответ пожалуйста.)